# Ehrenfest theorem initial conditions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics

The Ehrenfest theorem states that the expectation value of position $x$ obeys the following equation: $$m\frac{\mathrm{d^2}}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\langle x\rangle=\langle F(x)\rangle$$
But there I only need 2 initial conditions and for the wavefunction I need infinitely many initial conditions. So from where come all the initial conditions? I think that they come from the higher moments of the position operator but for the harmonic oscillator there are also infinitely many initial conditions and the centered moments vanish.

Comment: why do you need infinitely many conditions for the wavefunction?  You *know* the wavefunction here else you would be able to evaluate averages...

Comment: @ZeroTheHero yes but the expectation value of position of the harmonic oscillator behaves classical according to the Ehrenfest theorem. So if I know the initial position and momentum of the expectation value I know how the system behaves. My question is now why I need more initial conditions in quantum mechanics and where they come from.

Comment: But... a constraint of an expectation value, $d^2\langle x\rangle /dt ^2= -\omega^2 \langle x\rangle$ is not all there is to QM!?!! Indeed, there is an infinity of constraints of *x* -moments, which depend on the particular wavefunction involved....

Comment: well... this is an average so there are infinitely many states that will produce the same average.  Although this is not a time-dependent example, any normalizable state of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha_{2n} \vert 2n\rangle$ will have $\langle x\rangle=0$ so clearly the average value is not enough to specify the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So if I know the initial position and momentum of the expectation value I know how the system behaves. My question is now why I need more initial conditions in quantum mechanics and where they come from.

That's just it, you really *don't* know how the system behaves! While, for the quantum oscillator, the first moment has the magically classical property
$$
\frac{^2⟨⟩}{^2}=−^2⟨⟩,
$$
specified by two initial conditions, you can check that for the great majority of quantum oscillator states (barring coherent states) this dramatically fails for higher moments $\langle x^n\rangle$.

That is to say that many-many states described by the oscillator TDSE do "interesting things.

This is actually easiest to "see" in [deformation quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation#Simple_harmonic_oscillator), where the coordinate-space probability density profile is gotten by integrating out the momentum dependence of the rigidly rotating Wigner function.

That is, whereas the x-distribution's *mean* oscillates classically, the *rest* of it morphs and wiggles in a dramatic way, around that semiclassical mean.

For instance, look at the simplest [quantum flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation#/media/File:TwoStateWF.gif), that is, integrate over the *p*-axis.

There is much-much more in ICs you need to specify in QM, and they all come from the astounding $\hbar$-dependence of the Schroedinger equation. Choosing to focus on the semi-classical first moment is almost throwing out the baby with the ... ahh, stop that runaway metaphor!

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any reference where I can read about the $\hbar$-dependence of the SE?

Comment: Sorry, not really.... the classical limit sacrifices  the ℏ-dependent information of QM... Note the SE has one more independent variable, *x* , and  a different dependent variable, ψ, than Newton's equation of motion in the same dimension... What was *x(0)* , now has morphed to *ψ(x,0)*...